# Cross tabulating a query with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to come up with an efficient way of displaying some data but not succeeding at all.

The table is built dynamically from a few tables to show a row of headers with the columns populated showing the results by site e.g:

```
Site name | Column A | Column B | Column C => column headers continue from DB query
 Site A   | Result A | Result B | Result C
 Site B   | Result C | Result B | Result C
 Site C   | Result C | Result B | Result C

Results keep going vertically.
```

Here's the query I'm using

```
$risk_section=$row_risk_category['risksectid'];
    mysql_select_db($database_auditing, $auditing);
$qry_selfsites = sprintf("SELECT
tblself.siteid AS selfsite, 
tblsite.sitename AS sitename,
tblsite.address AS address, 
 tblpct.pctname AS pctname,
  tblresultsnew.total,
   tblresultsnew.auditid AS auditid,
    tblriskcategories.risksectid AS risksectid,
     tblriskcategories.risksection AS risksection
FROM tblself 
 LEFT JOIN tblresultsnew ON tblself.auditid = tblresultsnew.auditid 
  LEFT JOIN tblsite ON tblself.siteid = tblsite.siteid 
   LEFT JOIN tblpct ON tblsite.pctid = tblpct.pctid
    LEFT JOIN tblriskcategories ON
tblresultsnew.risksectid=tblriskcategories.risksectid 
WHERE tblsite.pctid IN (SELECT pctid FROM tblreportpcts WHERE
pctreportid='$pctreportid') 
 AND tblsite.sitetypeid IN (SELECT sitetypeid FROM tblreportsites WHERE
pctreportid='$pctreportid')
  AND tblself.year = %s 
   ORDER BY tblsite.pctid,tblsite.sitename", 
 GetSQLValueString($yearofrpt, "int"));
$selfsites = mysql_query($qry_selfsites, $auditing) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_selfsites = mysql_num_rows($selfsites);
```

So the question is, is there a way to get the data from the above query (or an adapted version thereof) to build the table dynamically with all the results lining up correctly?
 So far, I can only get it to build vertically.

Sorry, edit time (having worked with the answer below, I realised I hadn't got the question worded very well)

What I'm trying to get is a row of column headers from the query (`tblriskcategories.risksection AS risksection`) These populate horizontally to give the columns names.

Then underneath, the sitename is displayed with the result corresponding to the column header above i.e.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Sitename</th>
<?php while($row_selfsites=mysql_fetch_assoc($selfsites){  
 //loop through the section headers pulled from the DB (tblriskcategories)  
<th><?php echo $row_selfsites['risksection'];//show the section headers?></th>
<?php }   
//end header loop then start another loop to show a row for each site pulled
 //out by the query and show the relevant results in the correct column  
while($row_selfsites=mysql_fetch_assoc($selfsites)) {  
 //do the vertical drop matching the header rows with the sitenames from tblsite 
 //and the results from tblresultsnew 
?>  
<tr>  
<td><?php echo $row_selfsites['sitename'];?></td>  
<td><?php echo $row_selfsites['total'];  
//these need to grow to fit the headers and each site?></td>  
<tr>  
<?php } //end displayed data loop?>  
</table>
```

The relevant tables structure below:
    tblresultsnew resultsid,auditid,risksectid,total
    tblriskcategories risksectid, risksection
    tblself selfauditid,siteid,auditid
    tblsite siteid,sitename

So tblself holds the list of sites we need the data for and the relevant auditid,
tblresultsnew holds the results - the total column - for each risksectid and each auditid eg, one auditid can have approx 8 risksectid's each with corresponding total
tblriskcategories holds the column headings
tblsite holds the site data to make it mean something
  I hope this explains the question a little further.

Thanks again for all the help.
Dave

Comment: Can you add an example of what the final results-table should look like, or is the table presented in the question what you want it to look like and the question is "how do I make it look like this"?

Comment: Can you provide example input via http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: Hi, the table in the original question is pretty much how it would look - the way I see it (in my head at least) is building it with two while loops - one fills the horizontal headers

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows = array(
0 => array('headingA' => 'results1a', 'headingB' => 'results1b',  ),
1 => array('headingA' => 'results2a', 'headingB' => 'results2b',  ),
2 => array('headingA' => 'results3a', 'headingB' => 'results3b',  ),
);
// $rows is spoofing a db result set as an array
//var_dump( $rows );

$first = true ;
$header_row = "START TABLE <br />" ;
$data_rows = "";
foreach( $rows as $row ) {
  foreach( $row as $key=>$value ){
    if( $first === true ){
    $header_row .= "$key  | ";
    }
  $data_rows .= "$value |";
  }
if( $first ) $header_row .="<br />";

$data_rows .= "<br />";
$first = false;
}
echo $header_row . $data_rows . "END TABLE";
```

Gives:

```
START TABLE 
headingA | headingB | 
results1a |results1b |
results2a |results2b |
results3a |results3b |
END TABLE
```

Is that the kind of solution you are after?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the kind of thing I'm after, thanks very much. I'll have a fiddle and apply it to the page in question. Thanks you for the prompt responses. Dave